# User setting to opt-out of previously opted-in cookies

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to find a way to have a cookies consent bar that allows the users to explicitly accept or decline cookies. Then when they revisit, to give them option to change the setting, e.g. a user that previously opted-in would have an option to opt-out. I have spent a lot of time trying to find plugins and testing different suggestions to no avail, so I wondered if someone could advise me please.

Most plugins (e.g. https://github.com/erichard/awesome-gdpr) have an option for the user to accept/decline cookies on the first visit, but no option to change setting on repeat visit. I tried finding ways of deleting cookies (https://sitepoint.com/how-to-deal-with-cookies-in-javascript), but this does not let me remove cookies set by 3rd party applications (e.g. Twitter pixel or embedded timeline). I see from https://bbc.co.uk and https://bt.co.uk that it is technically possible for the users to opt-out once they have opted in, I'm stuck figuring out how that works.

Any guidance or pointers to plugins or resources in Javascript or C# would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is hard coding it on your own? Seems like a simple if statement.

Comment: I tried `deleteCookie("cookie_name");` example from [Sitepoint](https://sitepoint.com/how-to-deal-with-cookies-in-javascript). That works for cookies created through the website domain, but does not remove cookies created by 3rd party (Twitter etc).

Comment: You can't touch 3rd party cookies from a different domain.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing basic understanding here – So if a user opts-in and I load a 3rd party widget, which sets cookies, is there no way to remove these when user opts-out? Does that mean that when users opt out from BBC/BT, it keeps the third party cookies but stops tracking further?

Comment: You can't remove Twitter's cookies, but you can stop rendering the Twitter pixel onto the page, so that the cookies stop being sent to Twitter.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. Thanks @JohnWu